# how can limit the number of users in sugar crm CE

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I want to limit the user numbers in sugar crm, so that the admin will only be able to create certain number of user for eg 20-25 and if he try to create more than that, then it will show a message that "you've exceeded the user limit".

I tried to do it with putting a select user query on crm db and if it exceeds the limit then it will not show up the rest of the editview, but unfortunately its not working anymore, it works sometime but sometimes it failed.

Its a bit unstructured as I am using normal php syntax in those editviewdefs.php, detailviewdefs.php and other file.

Here is the syntax:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dbname","dbuser","dbpass");    
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {           
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .   mysqli_connect_error();              }

        $sql="SELECT * FROM users";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        echo $rowcount;
        if($rowcount<=25)
        {
        <<show rest of the edit view code eg $viewdefs ['Users'].......    etc >>
        }else
 {
    << show a message >>
 }      
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($con);  
    }
?>
```

I know that the above method that i am using is not structured and proper as this can be sorted out with certain sugar crm code.

So is there any systematic and structured way that I can create a certain function which will show up a message when i click on create new user and disable or hide user creation panel.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You only need to check in the editviewdefs.php because whenever New User creates editviewdefs.php loads and there you can check

- If `$bean->id` is empty New User is going to create
- Then you can perform user Limit check and restrict user
- Redirect your User **QuickCreate** form to User **FullForm**
- Improve your SQL query by adding Where clause `users.deleted=0`

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of the else for the mysqli error, looks to be on point

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dbname","dbuser","dbpass");    
    // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {           
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .   mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo $rowcount;
    if($rowcount<=25) {
            <<show rest of the edit view code eg $viewdefs ['Users'].......    etc >>
        } else {
            << show a message >>
        }      
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($con);  
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight but unfortunately this doesn't work for me, despite of adding code the module still showing those save and cancel buttons and when i click on it  is still saving records with blank details.

Also If I limit the number it will not allow me to edit the records as well as it hides the entire form.